# Scrape data and interact with webpage rendered in HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to scrape some data off of [a FanGraphs webpage](https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/season-stat-grid) as well as interact with the page itself. Since there are many buttons and dropdowns on the page to narrow down my search results, I need to be able to find the corresponding elements in the HTML. However, when I tried to use a 'classic' approach and use modules like `requests` and `urllib.requests`, the portions of the HTML containing the data I need did not appear.

### HTML Snippet

Here is a part of the HTML which contains the elements which I need.

```
<div id="root-season-grid">
    <div class="season-grid-wrapper">
        <div class="season-grid-title">Season Stat Grid</div>
            <div class="season-grid-controls">
                <div class="season-grid-controls-button-row">
                    <div class="fgButton button-green active isActive">Batting</div>
                    <div class="fgButton button-green">Pitching</div>
                    <div class="spacer-v-20"></div>
                    <div class="fgButton button-green active isActive">Normal</div>
                    <div class="fgButton button-green">Normal &amp; Changes</div>
                    <div class="fgButton button-green">Year-to-Year Changes</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The full CSS path:

`html > body > div#wrapper > div#content > div#root-season-grid div.season-grid-wrapper > div.season-grid-controls > div.season-grid-controls-button-row`

### Attempts

1. `requests` and `bs4`

```py
>>> res = requests.get("https://fangraphs.com/leaders/season-stat-grid")
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup4(res.text, features="lxml")
>>> soup.select("#root-season-grid")
[<div id="root-season-grid"></div>]
>>> soup.select(".season-grid-wrapper")
[]
```

So `bs4` was able to find the `<div id="root-season-grid"></div>` element, but could not find any descendants of that element.

2. `urllib` and `lxml`

```py
>>> res = urllib.request.urlopen("https://fangraphs.com/leaders/season-stat-grid")
>>> parser = lxml.etree.HTMLParser()
>>> tree = lxml.etree.parse(res, parser)
>>> tree.xpath("//div[@id='root-season-grid']")
[<Element div at 0x131e1b3f8c0>]
>>> tree.xpath("//div[@class='season-grid-wrapper']")
[]
```

Again, no descendants of the `div` element could be found, this time with `lxml`.

I started to wonder if I should be using a different URL address to pass to both `requests.get()` and `urlopen()`, so I created a `selenium` remote browser, `browser`, then passed `browser.current_url` to both function. Unfortunately, the results were identical.

3. `selenium`

I *did* notice however, that using `selenium.find_element_by_*` and `selenium.find_elements_by_*` *were* able to find the elements, so I started using that. However, doing so took a lot of memory and was extremely slow.

4. `selenium` and `bs4`

Since `selenium.find_element_by_*` worked properly, I came up with a very hacky 'solution'. I selected the full HTML by using the `"*"` CSS selector then passed that to `bs4.BeautifulSoup()`

```py
>>> browser = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
>>> html_elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("*")
>>> html = html_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML")
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
>>> soup.select("#root-season-grid")
[<div id="root-season-grid"><div class="season-grid-wrapper">...</div></div>]
>>> soup.select(".season-grid-wrapper")
[<div class="season-grid-wrapper">...</div>]
```

So this last attempt was somewhat of a success, as I *was* able to get the elements I needed. However, after running a bunch of unit test and a few integration tests for the module, I realized how inconsistent this is.

### Problem

After doing a bunch of research, I concluded the reason why Attempts (1) and (2) didn't work and why Attempt (3) is inconsistent is because the table in the page is rendered by JavaScript, along with the buttons and dropdowns. This also explains why the HTML above is not present when you click **View Page Source**. It seems that, when `requests.get()` and `urlopen()` are called, the JavaScript is not fully rendered, and whether `bs4`+`selenium` works depends on how fast the JavaScript renders. Are there any Python libraries which can render the JavaScript *before* returning the HTML content?

Hopefully this isn't too long of a question. I tried to condense as far as possible without sacrificing clarity.

Comment: Use Selenium instead for this site if it's dynamic Javascript and you want to interact with it using clicks. There is also an api if you want.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I have been using Selenium to atuomate the clicks and such, but the part that takes the longest is retrieving the "current settings", if you will. Since I plan on using this for larger projects with more data being scraped, I don't want to have the inconsistencies currently present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the page_source from Selenium and pass it to bs4.

```
browser.get("https://fangraphs.com/leaders/season-stat-grid")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, features="lxml")
print(soup.select("#root-season-grid"))
```

I'd recommend using their api however `https://www.fangraphs.com/api/leaders/season-grid/data?position=B&seasonStart=2011&seasonEnd=2019&stat=WAR&pastMinPt=400&curMinPt=0&mode=normal`

Comment: This worked much better than using the `"*"` CSS Selector. I also added a `WebDriverWait()` call before the `bs4.BeautifulSoup()` call, which pretty much eliminated the inconsistencies which I was facing beforehand.